# Spark PartitionByRange and driver memory

Tags: apache-spark, memory, out-of-memory, partitioning

I am doing partitionByRange for ~50 000 000 rows (~1.2 Tb deserialized java objects). Those are geodata that contains id, quadkey geohash and other fields. I was able to perform this shuffle transformation with driver.memory set to 80Gb (which is quite big). I do understand that all keys (partition columns) are collected on driver. But still I do not expect so aggressive memory usage. What I am missing here? Below some code:

```
preExportRdd.toDF
  .withColumn("provider", $"provider_id")
  .withColumn("hash", hash($"provider", $"qk10"))
  .withColumn("salt", rand())
  .repartitionByRange(partitionsNumber, $"hash", $"salt")
  .drop("hash", "salt")
  .write
  .partitionBy(partitionColumns:_*)
  .format("parquet")
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save(exportUrl)
```

Comment: Just curious, what are you running a repartition by range on a hash? Why not simply use a hash partitionner?

Comment: @Oli I have to solve skewing problem on the one hand, and I need to get ordered parquet data by hash  to use PushdownFilters further on consumer pipelines